# Which mythological character drowned in a lake during a sacrifice or mutual suicide?

Tags: story-identification, names, greek-myth

I am looking for a character in (I think) Greek mythology that may have been drowned as a form of sacrifice / gift to an underworld god. I found out about them via a painting so I believe they are Greek, but as I’ve researched it I believe it was mutual suicide and not sacrifice.

The closest I found to this was Eurydice, but different researches said different things about her death: either they say that she was bitten by a snake and then fell into a lake, or just that she was bitten by a snake. Hylas is another one who seem to have drowned but he was seduced and not a gift...

Comment: @phanton42 Yes! I just am not sure if they are greek, or if the death was exactly like this. I found out about them via a painting so I believe they are greek, but as I research I believe it was mutual suicide and not sacrifice. It would still be nice to find options other than greek though

Comment: @Xuu: if you’re trying to identify a mythological character you think you saw in a painting, then this is a story identification question, and is on-topic for the site. I’ve edited your question accordingly in case I’m right, and voted to re-open it. But it would help if you could add more details — what was the painting like? When did you see it? What details about the character do you remember?

Comment: Are you sure of the story behind it being mythological?  The image you describe made me think of [John Everett Millais' "Ophelia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophelia_%28painting%29) or possibly one of the [paintings](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1200&bih=671&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=where+the+wild+rose+grows&oq=where+the+wild+rose+grows&gs_l=img.3..0i24l2.87617.92502.0.92629.16.16.0.0.0.4.173.1532.11j4.15.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.img..7.9.858.-iShxXqHyA4) based on the Wild Rose murder ballad.

Comment: Can you post a picture or link to the painting you saw?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mythology, and not about science fiction or fantasy.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Narcissus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(mythology))? Whilst he was not exactly a suicide or ritual sacrifice, he did fall in love with his own reflection in a pool, and drowned in an effort to get to it.

The mutual suicide may be a reference to [Echo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(mythology))

Answer (score 1):

Googling the terms of your question brought me to [this site](http://www.whitedragon.org.uk/articles/rivers.htm), which speaks of rivers which require sacrifice at regular intervals, thought by some to be remnants of old Celtic rituals. The article I linked to argues that it is more likely that it is just a common way to bring meaning to deaths happening in the rivers at fairly regular intervals, and not remnants of old religions, considering that the kind of tales presented are common in much of the world. The only name I saw while skimming through the article was *Jan Coo*, and I am not sure if he is a sacrifice of the kind you look for. Some of the classical figures you mention in your question is also mentioned in the first paragraph, but it looks like you already have a good overview over those.

Comment: Ah yes I saw this site before! It provides some nice info on different death causes but the names are scarce/already heard of. I even forgot about Jan Coo, he is not a sacrifice but more of a tale to keep children away from rivers it seems.